# Is Veneziano amplitude able to explain the physical properties of strongly interacting hadrons (such as proton and neutron)?

Tags: string-theory, scattering, mesons

In theoretical physics, the [Veneziano amplitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veneziano_amplitude) refers to the discovery made in 1968 by Italian theoretical physicist Gabriele Veneziano that the Euler beta function, when interpreted as a scattering amplitude, has many of the features needed to explain the physical properties of strongly interacting mesons

Is Veneziano amplitude able to explain the physical properties of strongly interacting [hadron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadron)s (Proton, Neutron...)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70051/2451